# Under LINUX where should application initialization and support files be placed?

Tags: java, linux

I'm coding a Java application which when operational will start when the headless computer boots to control and save data from digital cameras. The app requires some initialization files, other support files, and a folder for logs which I have put in /usr/local/data.  The folder "data" is read/write for everyone.  A remote user will need to access initialization files from time to time.

Is this a good place for this?  Does LINUX use a standard place for application files and folders?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few standards to pick from.

IMHO, creating a user to run the process with configuration and data under its home directory is the best way to keep everything in one place (thats easy to find)

Comment: I'm going to try this first as my users are not very LINUX savvy.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There is the [Linux standard base](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Standard_Base) which defines these [LSB](https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/en/LSB) conventions.

Answer (score 2):

- Logs: /var/log/.log or /var/logs/.d/ for logs. Example: /var/log/samba.log or /var/log/samba.d/error.log
- Configuration files: /etc/ or /etc/.d/
- Data you want while running, but not for initial configuration: /var/cache/

Comment: Which can be understood as a tiny and incomplete summary of the LSB

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: I know. I was being lazy and just spewing from memory rather than looking up a canonical URL to the LSB and formatting a link in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Check File System hierarchy standard

http://www.pathname.com/fhs/

usually, application data stored in /var/lib/ , logs in /var/log/, /etc/ for config and so on.